Azure SQL Server database query suddenly exhausting DTUs
I have a Microsoft SQL Server database on Azure. Recently a query that has worked in the past started to max out DTUs and never returns. While attempting to diagnose the problem, I rewrote the query as a sequence of SELECT ... INTO #temp_table statements and these run in a fraction of a second.
My question is, why did the original query start failing? Should I rewrite all the other join queries to avoid this issue reoccurring?
Here's the query (table names have been changed).
SELECT      T_Primary.Id
FROM        T_Primary
INNER JOIN  T_Secondary ON T_Secondary.Id = T_Primary.T_Secondary_Id
WHERE       (T_Secondary.Path = @path OR T_Secondary.Path Like concat(@path, '\%'))
AND         T_Primary.Probability < 1
AND         T_Primary.Ignore = 0

Neither table is very big. T_Primary has 251464 rows and T_Secondary has 180032 rows.
There is a foreign key on T_Primary.T_Secondary_Id referencing T_Secondary.Id and an index supporting the foreign key.
The column definitions are as follows.
T_Primary.T_Secondary_Id  int            not null
T_Primary.Probability     float          not null
T_Primary.Ignore          bit            not null
T_Secondary.Id            int            not null  identity
T_Secondary.Path          nvarchar(255)  not null

Here's the stored procedure.
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_0001 (@path nvarchar(255) = NULL)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    SELECT      T_Secondary.id, 
                T_Secondary.path, 
                T_Secondary.name
    INTO        #temp1
    FROM        T_Secondary 
    WHERE       (T_Secondary.Path = @path OR T_Secondary.Path Like concat(@path, '\%'))
    ;

    SELECT      T_Primary.Id,
                T_Primary.[Probability],
                T_Primary.[Ignore]
    INTO        #temp2
    FROM        T_Primary 
    Inner JOIN  #temp1
    on          #temp1.Id = T_Primary.T_Secondary_Id
    ;

    SELECT      Id,
                Probability,
                Ignore
    FROM        #temp2
    WHERE       Probability < 1
    AND         Ignore = 0
    ;

END
GO

This stored procedure runs in a fraction of a second.
Here's a link to the query plan of the original query.
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=S1gC3bfmke
and here's a link to the query rewritten as a stored procedure
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ryLnTZGQJl

Please share the query plan for the slow and fast versions via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan

If this is a query that used to run OK and now is taking a long duration maybe the underlying data has changed or maybe the execution plan has changed. You can find the queryid in Query Store and use the tracked queries window in the UI to see if the longer durations are associated with a new plan, Do you have the FORCE LAST GOOD PLAN feature enabled?

Are you sure the "query plan of the original query" is the execution plan it is actually using when you see the high DTU usage? As it looks fine. It calculates the two index ranges for the = @path and Like concat(@path, '\%') ranges. Does seeks for both of those, and uses the output of these as the build input into a hash join onto another seek on Ignore = 0 AND Probability < 1 (so only does that seek once) - Can you check in querystore that this is definitely the plan it is using. And if so post the XML for the actual execution plan (not estimated) so we see where the time is spent

Though if it "never completes" you won't be able to get the actual execution plan with runtime timings. You can use the "Include Live Query Statistics" option to see what it is doing during execution and where it is getting hung up and provide that for a partial execution if a full one never completes. For something this simple to "never complete" and cause high DTU usage I would assume it is using inappropriate nested loops not the hash join shown TBH.
